# adding a static button at the centre|bottom of layout

Tags: android

I am trying to add a static button at the centre|bottom of my layout
P.s I need it with the cardview.

this is the code:
enter code here`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
enter code here`<android.support.v7.widget.CardView`
enter code here`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
enter code here`android:layout_width="match_parent"`
enter code here`<RelativeLayout`
enter code here`android:layout_width="366dp"`
[enter code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed7Rw.png)`android:layout_height="match_parent">

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSubName"
    android:layout_width="161dp"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="104dp"
    android:text="Present"
    android:textColor="#44d515" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
    android:layout_width="79dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
    android:text="Absent"
    android:textColor="#de2816" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You use [layout_alignParentBottom](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_alignParentBottom) and [layout_centerHorizontal](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_centerHorizontal) on a button in your `RelativeLayout` to achieve this, like so:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="CLICK ME"
 />
```

Comment: Wouldn't that make to appear the button in each cardview?i want only one button in the whole recycler view to post the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 1 button in the whole recycler view, then you would create it as a separate item with a different item type / view holder.